# css padding ignored in opera

Tags: css, html-lists, opera, padding

I have form in page index.html

```
<div class = "bottom_r">
    <h1>Get in Touch</h1>
    <form action="index.html" method="post">
      <ul>
        <li><input class = "input" type="text" name="fname" value = "Name:" /></li>
        <li><input class = "input" type="text" name="lname" value = "Email:" /></li>
        <li><textarea class = "textarea" >Message:</textarea></li>
        <li><input class="text_button" type="submit" value="Submit" /></li>
      </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

and css style in style.css

```
.bottom_r {
    float: left;
    width: 262px;
    height: 215px;
    margin: 0;
}


.bottom_r ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}


.bottom_r li {      
    margin: 0;    
    padding-left: 50px;           
}
```

But padding: `padding-left: 20px;` work only with first `<li>`, this problem is only in opera, in all browser it working pretty, I can't find the problem, please help :)

Code online: http://cssdesk.com/8xrgD

Comment: which version of Opera do you use? I don't see any difference between Opera and FF

Comment: Nevest version, today updated.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in Opera 11.62 or 12.0 (fresh upgrade)

Comment: Look here i add all code http://cssdesk.com/8xrgD ;)

Comment: @user1069874 ok, now I can see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change line 62:

```
.main > ul li
```

Answer (score 1):

By the way... your problem ist your

```
.main li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Just define ist where you need it and not in the whole .main

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's the reason for this, I can reproduce it but can't see what's the problem, however if move the 50px padding from the `<li>` to their `<ul>`, it works fine:

```
.bottom_r ul {
    padding: 50px;
}
```

see http://cssdesk.com/WERUf

Answer (score 0):

In the last instance if nothing else works, use :

```
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:10000), not all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
      .class {proprieties}
 }
```

Works only for opera.